# sh: app: command not found when trying to do runApps

Tags: python

I'm following a tutorial on a gui app (Dev Ed) but I'm stuck on runApps. One of the lines include `os.startfile` which I know is not available on Mac (which I'm on) so I used:

```py
def runApps():
    for app in apps:
        os.system("app")
```

when I run the code it shows `"sh: app: command not found"`

Comment: Remove the quotes on `os.system("app")` -> `os.system(app)`

Comment: It still doesn't work.. now I get the error "sh: /Applications/Alfred: No such file or directory"

Comment: It seems your application Alfred is of a type that Windows system would recognize how to run it (using which program), but the Unix shell does not. Is it a python program? You may want to add a link to the tutorial you are following in your question, or show more code if you want people to answer.